# Can anyone explain why creating a histogram with two conditions shows incorrect distribution in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to create a histogram with data from two different conditions (A and B in the example below). I want to plot both distributions in the same plot using `geom_histogram` in R.

However, it seems that for condition A, the distribution of the whole data set is shown (instead of only A).

In the example below, three cases are shown:

1. Plotting A and B
2. Plotting only A
3. Plotting only B

You will see that the distribution of A is not the same when you compare 1) and 2).

Can anyone explain why this occurs and how to fix this problem?

```
set.seed(5)

# Create test data frame 
test <- data.frame(
  condition=factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each=200)),
  value =c(rnorm(200, mean=12, sd=2.5), rnorm(200, mean=13, sd=2.1))
)

# Create separate data sets
test_a <- test[test$condition == "A",]
test_b <- test[test$condition == "B",]

# 1) Plot A and B
ggplot(test, aes(x=value, fill=condition)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25, alpha=.5) +
  ggtitle("Test A and AB")

# 2) Plot only A
ggplot(test_a, aes(x=value, fill=condition)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25, alpha=.5) +
  ggtitle("Test A")

# 3) Plot only B
ggplot(test_b, aes(x=value, fill=condition)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25, alpha=.5) +
  ggtitle("Test B")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative for visualization, not to supplant MichaelDewar's answer:

```r
ggab <- ggplot(test, aes(x=value, fill=condition)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25, alpha=.5, position = "identity") +
  ggtitle("Test A and AB") +
  xlim(5, 20) +
  ylim(0, 13)

# 2) Plot only A
gga <- ggplot(test_a, aes(x=value, fill=condition)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25, alpha=.5) +
  ggtitle("Test A") +
  xlim(5, 20) +
  ylim(0, 13)

# 3) Plot only B
ggb <- ggplot(test_b, aes(x=value, fill=condition)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25, alpha=.5) +
  ggtitle("Test B") +
  xlim(5, 20) +
  ylim(0, 13)

library(patchwork) # solely for a quick side-by-side-by-side presentation
gga + ggab + ggb + plot_annotation(title = 'position = "identity"')
```

[image]

The key in this visualization is adding `position="identity"` to the first hist (the others do not need it).

Alternatively, one could use `position="dodge"` (this is best viewed on the console, it's a bit difficult on this small snapshot).

[image]

And for perspective, `position = "stack"`, the default, showing "A" with a demonstrably altered histogram.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The plots are stacked in the A+B plot.  So the A bars start at the top of the B bars.  Also, the scaling on the axes are different.  It's also possible that the bins have different endpoints.

So, yes, the A+B plot is showing the total distribution.  The fill helps you see the contribution from each of the A and B.

If you want to overlay the two plots, use:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x=value, fill=condition)) +
    geom_histogram(data = test_a, binwidth = 0.25, alpha=.5) +
    geom_histogram(data = test_b, binwidth = 0.25, alpha=.5) +
    ggtitle("Test A and AB")
```

Comment: The "stacked" is the key component, I believe. Correcting for x/y limits does not reveal much.

Comment: Thanks!! Is there a way to plot the data in a non-stacked fashion, similar to plotting 2) and 3) in the same plot?

Comment: I just added a change.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I was about to add an answer with this, but you got the point first ... if you use `geom_histogram(..., position="identity")` to the first (full `test` data) and fix the axes to be the same, the matching is clear.

Comment: @MichaelDewar Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @r2evans You are right, "stacked" is the key component. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I added an answer for context; feel free to grab the components and put it here and I'll delete my answer (no competition).

Comment: @r2evans Using ```position="identity"``` means circumventing the separation of the data. Convenient, thanks!

Comment: Actually, @count_matrix, I'm not new to `ggplot2`, but I've not played with `geom_histogram(..., position=)` at all. This was a good excuse to play around (since I strongly suspected what the issue was), and now the three `position`s shown together is a good example.

Comment: BTW, which to choose for an answer is yours, of course, but I had added my code as a demo against MichaelDewar's first answer. At least give MD an upvote for the credit earned.

Comment: @r2evans I would accept both answers as answers if it were possible! I clicked on the "This answer is useful" button on MD's answer, is there anything else I can do?

Comment: nope, thanks :-)